# Ruby floating number subtraction wrong?

Tags: ruby, numbers, floating-accuracy, rounding-error

Can anyone explain why the following Ruby routine gives me a 2.0 as a result? I think rounding the floats is the root of the error.

```
puts(999_999_999_999_999_9.0 - 999_999_999_999_999_8.0);

= 2.0
```

The same error?

```
puts(999_999_999_999_999_3.0 - 999_999_999_999_999_2.0);

= 0.0
```

I'm running Ruby 1.9.3p448 (2013-06-27) [i386-mingw32].

Comment: Yes this is floating point rounding. The numbers you have entered cannot be represented with complete accurately using Ruby's `Float` class. The imprecision is not spread evenly, and the representation of your second two numbers is actually identical - it is the same `Float` object.

Answer (score 0):

These numbers are already too big and Ruby cannot count them in ones already - it can't represent so many ones. So, it count them in twos. Numbers twice bigger will be counted in fours, and so on.

That depends on the number of digits that can *mantissa* of a float number accept. It is always mentioned in the base types description.